# Discrepancy in #group members

Tags: google-apps-script

I have executed the code snippet in the Apps Script page for listing the members of a group
(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_group#getUsers); I am only interested in counting the members for showing this number on a web page.

I get 192 members while the web interface of Google Groups for the same group tells me there are 222 members.

I am owner of that group; there were a few banned members, not enough to explain the difference.

Does anybody know why ?

Comment: Hmmn, are any of the members of the group - other groups themselves? Perhaps the UI is expanding all the groups into actual users and the API is only counting total email addresses in the group?

Answer (score 0):

The GroupsApp service returns User objects for each member of the group that corresponds to an actual Google account. Email addresses without corresponding Google accounts are not returned. You can see further discussion of this behavior in [Issue 1157](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1157#c7).